# Encoding issue with UTF-8 data in linux

Tags: r

I am trying to run C5.0 algorithm to generate rules. The data includes Japanese characters. The same piece of code is working in windows and in Linux, it is giving an error stating bad value.

```
*** line 1 of `undefined.data': bad value of `������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������' for attribute `Field1'
```

The data inside the file looks like

```
Id,Field1,Field2,OutCome
4834680,Ｆｏｃｕｓ　Ｐｔｅ　Ｌｔ,シンガポール・ドル,Sales Singapore
4834680,Ｆｏｃｕｓ　Ｐｔｅ　Ｌｔ,シンガポール・ドル,Sales Singapore
4834680,Ｆｏｃｕｓ　Ｐｔｅ　Ｌｔ,シンガポール・ドル,Sales Singapore
4834680,Ｆｏｃｕｓ　Ｐｔｅ　Ｌｔ,シンガポール・ドル,Sales Singapore
 111633,ＡＭＥＲＩＣＡ　Ｌ,アメリカ・ドル,Sales America
 111633,ＡＭＥＲＩＣＡ　Ｌ,アメリカ・ドル,Sales America
```

Assuming the file is stored in the CSV file, Here is my code.

```
columnNames<-"Field2"
targetColumn<-"OutCome"
rulesFileName<-"rules.txt"
outputPath<-"./"

  library(C50)
  library(dplyr)
  c50data <- read.csv("./sampleutf8japanese.csv",header = TRUE,sep = ",",encoding = "UTF-8")
  c50data<-c50data[,2:4]
  for(i in 1:ncol(c50data)){c50data[,i]=as.factor(c50data[,i])}
  frmla = paste(targetColumn,"~",".")
  ruleModel <- C5.0(as.formula(frmla), data=c50data, rules=TRUE)
  print(summary(ruleModel))
  write(capture.output(summary(ruleModel)), paste(c(outputPath, rulesFileName), collapse=''))
```

Windows output of the rules file looks like.

```
Call:
C5.0.formula(formula = as.formula(frmla), data = c50data, rules = TRUE)


C5.0 [Release 2.07 GPL Edition]     Mon Feb 20 14:48:22 2017
-------------------------------

Class specified by attribute `outcome'

Read 6 cases (3 attributes) from undefined.data

Rules:

Rule 1: (2, lift 2.3)
    Field1 = ＡＭＥＲＩＣＡ　Ｌ
    ->  class Sales America  [0.750]

Rule 2: (4, lift 1.2)
    Field1 = Ｆｏｃｕｓ　Ｐｔｅ　Ｌｔ
    ->  class Sales Singapore  [0.833]

Default class: Sales Singapore


Evaluation on training data (6 cases):

            Rules     
      ----------------
        No      Errors

         2    0( 0.0%)   <<


       (a)   (b)    <-classified as
      ----  ----
         2          (a): class Sales America
               4    (b): class Sales Singapore


    Attribute usage:

    100.00% Field1


Time: 0.0 secs
```

In linux the error is as follows

```
Call:
C5.0.formula(formula = as.formula(frmla), data = c50data, rules = TRUE)


C5.0 [Release 2.07 GPL Edition]     Mon Feb 20 04:13:30 2017
-------------------------------

Class specified by attribute `outcome'

*** line 1 of `undefined.data': bad value of `????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????' for attribute `Field1'

*** line 1 of `undefined.data': bad value of `??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????' for attribute `Field2'

*** line 2 of `undefined.data': bad value of `????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????' for attribute `Field1'

*** line 2 of `undefined.data': bad value of `??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????' for attribute `Field2'

*** line 3 of `undefined.data': bad value of `????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????' for attribute `Field1'

*** line 3 of `undefined.data': bad value of `??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????' for attribute `Field2'

*** line 4 of `undefined.data': bad value of `????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????' for attribute `Field1'

*** line 4 of `undefined.data': bad value of `??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????' for attribute `Field2'

*** line 5 of `undefined.data': bad value of `??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????' for attribute `Field1'

*** line 5 of `undefined.data': bad value of `??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????' for attribute `Field2'

Error limit exceeded
```

Couldn't figure out what could be the issue.

Comment: I can confirm that the same error arise on Mac OSX, except that I get things like ``bad value of `¸æô¶îº¸æò∂àº¸æç¶Ñº¸æô¶îº¸æôÜàº¸æô£†º¸æô¶îº¸æôÜàº¸æå≥†º¸æô¶îº¸æôÜàº¸æçì§º¸æô¶îº¸æôÜàº¸æå≥§º¸æå∂îº¸æåÉ†º¸æåÉ†º¸æô¶îº¸æò∂àº¸æåÜàº¸æô¶îº¸æôÜàº¸æçÉ§º¸æô¶îº¸æôÜàº¸æçì†º¸æå∂îº¸æåÉ†º¸æåÉ†º¸æô¶îº¸æò∂àº¸æò∂Ñº¸æô¶îº¸æôÜàº¸æçÉ§º' for attribute `Field1'`` instead of `?`s.

Comment: Thanks for your analysis on Mac OSX @plannapus . the only noticeable difference till now in my analysis is locale. The values of Sys.getlocale() is different in both the OS. Still i don't know how to solve this problem